# Contents panel missing in Catalog window of ArcMap?

Tags: arcmap, panel, catalog-window

The "contents panel" (not the "Table of Contents") is missing from the Catalog window embedded in ArcMap 10.6.

How can I make the "contents panel" visible?

Comment: What you are referring to is not ArcCatalog. It is the Catalog window of ArcMap. Somewhere along the top of that there is a button that rotates it between tree, contents and split views.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answer as [suggested by @PolyGeo](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/298315/contents-panel-missing-in-catalog-window-of-arcmap#comment479853_298315): press the button at the top of the Catalog window of ArcMap.

[image]

It rotates between tree, contents and split views.